# Is there a recommended PPA for Ghostscript 9 on 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, ghostscript

Recently we keep receiving PDFs that hang Ghostscript at 100% CPU when printed. Since at the office we are still on Lucid, I tried printing those same PDFs from a Precise VM as a test, and they work nicely.
Sadly we can't migrate right now to Precise, so I was thinking of upgrading just Ghostscript (Lucid has 8.71 while Precise 9.x), is there a PPA I could use?

Comment: Have you considered compiling from source until you can migrate, or is that not an option?

Comment: Well in the end we just migrated to 12.04, I've left this question open in case someone had the same problem :)

Comment: The 12.04 repository uses Ghostscript 9.05 and latest version is 9.10. The 12.04 repository version will not be updated any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after more than 5 years, I'd say such a PPA doesn't exist.

Answer (score -3):

http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

Download and install from source.